# Cross platform Word Document encoding issue

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, ms-word

I have a PHP script that generates Word documents (`.doc`).

It takes characters from HTML entities, e.g. `&#928;`, and decodes them with PHP's `html_entity_decode()`.

```
$line = html_entity_decode($text, ENT_NOQUOTES | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8");
```

When opening the resulting file in Libre Office on Linux, the file loads correctly (characters are correctly encoded). However when opening in Microsoft Word on Windows, the non-ASCII characters are incorrect. For example, the capital Greek letter PI (`Π`) is rendered as the Chinese character (`螤`).

I figure there is a missing header or metadata that tells word that the data is encoded in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Hate to look the fool, but I've answered my own question.

Just after opening the file for writing, I added:

```
fwrite($fp, pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf));
```

This writes the UTF-8 byte order mark to the start of the file.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark